# Escaping requirements for Twig / Timber within WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, sanitization, timber

I'm using the Twig templating system as well as the Timber plugin within WordPress and one thing the Timber pages say about escaping is that:

> By default, Timber does not escape the output of standard tags (i.e. {{ post.field }}). If you want to enable autoescape behavior simply add these lines to functions.php:

https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/escapers/

Does this mean if I turn this on I won't need to do any escaping whatsoever? Not for the html body, attributes, url's etc?

Additionally, if I *don't* turn this on, does this mean it is recommended do do something like this:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="main-nav">
        {% for item in menu.get_items %}
            <li class="{{ fn('esc_attr', (item.classes | join(' '))) }}">
                <a href="{{ item.get_link|e('esc_url') }}">{{ item.title|e }}</a>

                {% if item.children %}

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        {% for child in item.children %}

                            <li class="sub-menu-item">
                                <a href="{{ child.get_link|e('esc_url') }}">{{ child.title|e }}</a>
                            </li>

                        {% endfor %}

                    </ul>

                {% endif %}

            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I used `fn('esc_attr', item.classes)` to utilise the WordPress escaper `esc_attr` as it doesn't appear like Timber has an escape for attributes and the Twig version wasn't added to **1.9**, but it appears Timber is on **1.35.2**.

Are there any disadvantages to auto-escaping? Doesn't seem to me like there would be unless you were planning on not escaping everything? ...and you can always utilise `|raw` if you don't want something escaped I would assume?

Comment: I'd say only use auto-escape if you don't deal with and don't display user data

Comment: Everything has disadvantages, like using a Q&A website to realize your potential.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any disadvantages to auto-escaping?

No. It is recommended (and the default functionality) as outputting raw should be something the developer thinks about at development time and not an after thought.

Lets say you have this: `<h1>{{ variable }}</h1>` here is a table of what this would look like:

```
| Auto Escape | Default Functionality |
| ----------- | --------------------- |
|  Disabled   |  {{ variable|raw }}   |
|  Enabled    |  {{ variable|e }}     |
```

In twig we have these filters [`|raw`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) and [`|escape` (or `|e`)](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html).

> Does this mean if I turn this on I won't need to do any escaping whatsoever? 
>   Not for the html body, attributes, url's etc?

I cannot say for sure but I am also going to say no. I believe what it means by auto escaping is simply what I mentioned above. It will not automatically select an escaping strategy (so it won't know when to use `|e('html')`) but instead run everything through the standard `|e` unless manually ran through `|e('html')` or `|raw`.

Comment: Hmmmm..... with that in mind it seems that *not* using auto-escaping would be the better idea as then you would always be running them through the correct escaping mechanism!?

Answer (score 3):

Escaping is a vital operation to avoid cross site scripting (XSS) attacks. Auto-escaping is very helpful. However, here are some things to watch out for:

**Double Escaping**: If you are escaping in WordPress and in Timber, then you will see funny things like the ampersand being converted to an html entity.

```
 echo htmlentities('<strong>');
 echo '<BR><BR>';
 echo htmlentities(htmlentities('<strong>'));
```

Outputs in a web page:

> <strong>
>
> &lt;strong&gt;

**Disabling escaping in two places and missing it:**

While the first issue is ugly and bad for UI, the second issue can cause your website to be a vector of attack:

```
echo '<script>alert("I own your website");</script>';
```

Your website should either strip this or display it as text without executing it (i.e. escape it).

End result: Always escape with one, never with both.

Should you disable WordPress escaping or Twig escaping? That's a personal choice. Leaving Twig escaping disabled and WordPress escaping enabled is probably a bit less tedious.

Just make sure that if you're getting (unescaped) data from a location other than WordPress, you escape it using WordPress filters or Twig. My personal preference is to aim for consistency.

If Timber disables auto-escaping, then my inclination would be to leave it be, but test, test, test.